# How do you convert a (really big) pandas series datetime where each row has to be converted to a different timezone?

Tags: python, pandas

pd.tz_convert() only accepts strings and pytz.timezone objects. If I try putting a mask on the conversion, to select each group of timezones, it just creates a copy of the dataframe instead of changing those values inplace. How can I do it?

This is the rough idea on the code:

```
mail_events['datetime_delivery'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(mail_events['datetime_delivery']).tz_convert(mail_events['timezone'])
```

data sample:

```
                  datetime_delivery                    datetime_open  \
0  2018-01-24 16:01:10.153029+00:00 2018-01-24 16:37:44.877778+00:00   
1  2018-01-24 16:01:10.153029+00:00 2018-01-24 19:36:35.485069+00:00   
2  2018-01-24 16:01:10.153029+00:00 2018-01-31 14:28:44.796184+00:00   
10 2018-01-24 16:01:10.124305+00:00 2018-01-25 00:46:52.078911+00:00   
11 2018-01-24 16:01:10.124305+00:00 2018-01-25 15:59:05.280755+00:00   

                 distance           timezone  
0  0 days 00:36:34.724749  America/Sao_Paulo  
1  0 days 03:35:25.332040  America/Sao_Paulo  
2  6 days 22:27:34.643155  America/Sao_Paulo  
10 0 days 08:45:41.954606  America/Sao_Paulo  
11 0 days 23:57:55.156450  America/Sao_Paulo
```

expected output (changes to datetime_delivery):

```
                      datetime_delivery                    datetime_open  \
0  2018-01-24 14:01:10.153029-02:00 2018-01-24 16:37:44.877778+00:00   
1  2018-01-24 14:01:10.153029-02:00 2018-01-24 19:36:35.485069+00:00   
2  2018-01-24 14:01:10.153029-02:00 2018-01-31 14:28:44.796184+00:00   
10 2018-01-24 14:01:10.124305-02:00 2018-01-25 00:46:52.078911+00:00   
11 2018-01-24 14:01:10.124305-02:00 2018-01-25 15:59:05.280755+00:00   

                 distance           timezone  
0  0 days 00:36:34.724749  America/Sao_Paulo  
1  0 days 03:35:25.332040  America/Sao_Paulo  
2  6 days 22:27:34.643155  America/Sao_Paulo  
10 0 days 08:45:41.954606  America/Sao_Paulo  
11 0 days 23:57:55.156450  America/Sao_Paulo
```

Comment: Can you add data sample and expected output?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I've edited the original question.

Comment: It is dupe, so check dupe answers.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, and sorry for the dupe.

Comment: You are welcome, please delete it.